# Javascript add properties with the same name to an object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        obj.userId = elements[i].id 
    } 

// output: obj = {userId: 1, userId: 2, userId: 3.....etc}
```

Is it possible in some way? Thanks.

Comment: I think you can not use same key, it will override.
`obj["userId"] = elements[i].id ;`

Comment: it is not possible in an object. please use an array for this purpose like ` [{userId: 1}, {userId: 2}, {userId: 3}]`.

Comment: key name of same object must be unique

Comment: So answer is "not possiple". You could say obj ['userId'+i]=elements [i].id

Answer (score 4):

keys in `Object` must be unique, you can try use `Array`, like this

```
var obj = [];
var data = {};
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   data = {
     userId: elements[i].id 
   };
   obj.push(data);
} 

// [ {userId: 1}, {userId: 2} ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON RFC says "the names within an object SHOULD be unique" - [see here for more info](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) however should your object have a duplicate key the last occurrence will be used.

An array would be a better solution for your data.

Comment: I know, but later i must merge this data with another object, not with array